# Image Transformation

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, transformation

I've been reading a lot about information transformations/distortions on here and elsewhere, and they seem to fall into two categories: distortion of the pixels of the image while maintaining the original boundaries, or transformations like rotation, scaling, etc. What I would like to do is pretty different.

I would like to warp a rectangular image into a polygon. In particular, I want to warp an image into each one of the 50 United States. Simple mapping of the state and then cropping out parts of the image that don't fit in is **not** acceptable. These images have borders, and then someone's face contained inside of them. I did find this really cool paper on [content-aware image resizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving) ([paper](http://portal.acm.org.ezproxy.library.wisc.edu/citation.cfm?id=1276390&CFID=17217998&CFTOKEN=94588357)), and while it would let me keep the focus of the images (the face) undistorted, it still maps to 4 corners. For my initial test, I don't care about warping the faces too.

Does anyone have suggestions? Research papers, code, Wikipedia pages, GIMP plugins, software tools, etc welcome.

Comment: I think the link you posted doesn't work unless you have an ACM subscription.  Are you talking about Seam Carving? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [multipoint distortion in ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards) can work for you.

Comment: I'll have to look at it this weekend or next, and I'll let you know. Looks promising though.

Comment: Works about as well as I could probably expect. Thanks!